# Compare each element in same column with other set of records in R

Tags: r

[image]

I have data table in which need to populate Result column based on the comparison/match between element to element in the same column from two different Types. 
Here we need compare the values in same column one by one between object 1 and object 2 and not column to column.

if you can see Result value for first row i have mentioned 1,0,1 means in Col-1 of Object-1 is matched in Col-1 of Object-2. similarly 0 for col-2 and 1 for col-3.

Appreciate any solutions in **R** with package or without **package**

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example. Don't post picture; rather post your dataset. The logic you are describing to obtain `Result` is not very clear. Since there are many rows of both `Object1` and `Object2` I don't get which row of `Object1` must be compared to which row of `Object2`.

Comment: In your real life, is there only two values for Type and only three columns Col1 to Col3?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand well your problem. And not knowing what are the limits in number of values for Type and of columns, here is a general solution with the tidyverse :

```
# Your data (there seems to be a problem on line3 result)
df <- read.table(text=
"Type Col1 Col2 Col3 Result
O1 A B F 1,0,1
O1 B D S 0,1,0
O1 C F R 0,0,0
O1 D D D 1,1,1
O2 A F F 1,0,1
O2 D D D 1,1,1",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df %>% select(-Result) %>% mutate(id=row_number()) -> df1
df1 %>% gather(k,v,-Type,-id) -> df2
crossing(df2,df2) %>%
   filter((Type!=Type1)&(k==k1)) %>%
   mutate(z=as.integer(v==v1)) %>%
   group_by(id,id1,k) %>%
   arrange(desc(z)) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>%
   group_by(id,id1) %>% arrange(k) %>%
   summarise(n=sum(z),z=paste(z,collapse=","))%>%
   filter(n>=max(n)) %>%
   select(-id1,-n) %>%
   inner_join(df1,.,by="id")
#  Type Col1 Col2 Col3 id     z
#1   O1    A    B    F  1 1,0,1
#2   O1    B    D    S  2 0,1,0
#3   O1    C    F    R  3 0,1,0
#4   O1    D    D    D  4 1,1,1
#5   O2    A    F    F  5 1,0,1
#6   O2    D    D    D  6 1,1,1
```